# Never get AccountManager.KEY_INTENT from getAuthToken request

Tags: android

On JellyBean device.

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html) to request an oauth2 token, e.g.

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getActivity());
am.invalidateAuthToken(MY_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null);
am.getAuthToken(aGoogleAccount, MY_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, 
    new OnTokenAcquired(), new Handler(new OnError()));
```

and then make the check as per the later code sample:

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
@Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
        ...
        Intent launch = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
        if (launch != null) {
            startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I never get a KEY_INTENT. I understand the following:

> There may be many reasons for the authenticator to return an Intent. It may be the first time the user has logged in to this account. Perhaps the user's account has expired and they need to log in again, or perhaps their stored credentials are incorrect. Maybe the account requires two-factor authentication or it needs to activate the camera to do a retina scan. It doesn't really matter what the reason is. If you want a valid token, you're going to have to fire off the Intent to get it.

However, the `getAuthToken` always results in the permission screen, or login screen, appearing before the code hits the `run` method at which point the token is valid. I've tried:

1. Turning on 2 step authentication. Account login is requested before `run` so always have the token in `run`.
2. Changing the password on the server. Again account login is requested before `run` so always have the token in `run`.

Don't have the ability to try a retina scan so somewhat at a loss.

**EDIT 1** The problem I have is that there may be a circumstance where I will get a `KEY_INTENT` and so I'd rather test this code path now rather when when it's out in the field.

Thanks in advance.

Peter.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? BTW, you should probably be using Google Play Services for this, it has a much better user experience.

Comment: Updated question as to why. I haven't looked at the Google Play Services and whether I can use it to get a token to be used to acess the Google Cloud Print service.

Comment: There are a lot of 'maybe's' in the description, so it is entirely possible that there is now way to force it for OAuth. Google Play Services supports OAuth 2 tokens, so should work for anything that uses those. Haven't used it with the print service though.

Comment: Thanks. Agree that if it returns an OAuth2 token then accessing the print services should be fine. Yep, far too many 'maybe's' in their description and somewhat at odds with the actual behaviour of the API given that I tested two-factor authentication.

Comment: How are you creating / retrieving the `aGoogleAccount`?

Comment: `am.getAccountsByType("com.google");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a chance to do something similar on a project. This not the exactly the same as your code,  and I still say that the callback docs have too many 'maybes' to be certain of how it should work, but if you use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) passing `false` for `notifyAuthFailure`, you will get an intent with the re-login screen if you change the password or enable 2FA. This is for ClientLogin, but should work similarly for OAuth 2 (not tested though). Something like:

```
// using Calendar ClientLogin for simplicity
Bundle authResult = am.getAuthToken(account, "cl", false, null, null).getResult();
if (authResult.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
  Intent authIntent = authResult.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
  // start activity or show notification
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. I see that this method was deprecated in API 14 but if it works it will at least allow me to test my code path.

Comment: Also works with non deprecated method by setting the callback to be null.

Comment: The whole deprecation thing on Android is a bit funny -- if you want your app to run on anything below API 14, you *have to* use the older method (at least on those platforms). I haven't looked at the source, but both should be doing essentially the same thing, the newer one with more options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `getResult()`, like this:

```
Intent launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting, I copied code from developer.android webpage. My actual code does make `getResult()` call first. Have updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the version of getAuthToken which uses an Activity to invoke the access authorization prompt. That version of getAuthToken does not return an intent since the supplied activity is used to launch the corresponding intent. If you want to manually launch an intent, use the version of getAuthToken that was deprecated in API level 14. See the following for more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29